# Windows script replace entire line

Tags: windows, shell

On a windows script i need to replace entire line number of a file (eg: line number 15) with the contents of a variable.
I don´t have a string to search for it will depend of the file but the line number is always the same.
The file in question is of type xml, if necessary i can install any tool that could help me doing this using the windows scripting.

I am out of options, once i see many options of achieving this on linux but not on windows.
Already tried find and replace but since my files are different i don´t have a search pattern

Comment: One more reason for me to avoid Windows batch scripting. Honestly, why don't you use one of the bash- or zsh-implementatins available for Windows and don't have to worry about such problems in the future? Another possibility would be to install Perl or Ruby on Windows and use that for such scripting tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem in dire straits, there are standalone versions the unix/linux `sed` utility for windows you can install without requiring cygwin or MSYS2 etc.

Sorry, I can't provide a link. It will be better for you to search as you're aware of your local OS version and any other details that might impact which version you select.

But

```
 echo "1
> 2
> 3
> 4" | sed '3s/.*/Something/'
```

**output**

```
1
2
Something
4
```

Shows one approach.

IHTH

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction when you said that i can use sed on Windows command.

Comment: Glad that helped and glad you mentioned you were open to installing any software. New (post 1991 (-;!) version of `sed` offer the `-i` option, which means `inplace`. Of course it is still writing to a new file and swapping names at the end, but it is convenient rather than `sed 'script' file > newFile && mv newFile file`.  (you would sed just `sed -i 'scrript' file` (unless on a Mac (`-i''`) )). Good luck!

Comment: I ended up installing awk on windows and used the following to replace line 16:
awk -v x="Replace line with this text" "NR==16 {$0=x} 1" STATS.cfg > STATS.tds

Comment: `awk` works too! Good show and Good luck.